# How to resolve "Unable to start debugging on the web server"

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, module, dotnetnuke

I am creating a module on Dotnetnuke project template, and i want to make the release of that module. But when I select "release" from dropdownlist and after that click on debug button. I got an error below on iis7 and windows7.

```
Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See
help for common configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information.
```

I don't understand why it comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to DEBUG, you shouldn't choose RELEASE from the dropdown list, that will build the module in RELEASE mode, not DEBUG mode.

You should also check to see if you have enabled Debugging in the web.config of your DNN Development site.

Update:
If you want to package the module, after choosing RELEASE from the dropdown list, choose BUILD not the DEBUG option in visual studio.

Comment: I want to make the release of that module, so what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

One other consideration is to ensure that your web.config compilation node is set to debug="true".  This is of particular interest if you configSource this setting into a separate file.